# Is it possible to use Tabwidget on 2 rows

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

Currently i use TabWidget with 4 tabs on 1 Rows.
Each tab have a text description, not an icon.
I want to insert 1 or 2 Tabs more, but it's not possilbe on the rows because on small screen text description will be too small.

I wonder if a can add antoher tab row (just below the first row) with 1 or 2 tab inside?

My code is:

```
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerPadding="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="65dp" >

            <!-- Tab 1 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_alimentation"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Tab 2 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_lance1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Tab 3-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_tab_resultat"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Tab 4 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_lance2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Do you think it's possible,?

thx,

Comment: 1) `TabLayout` is the new default way of adding tabs to your application. 2) When there are more tabs than can fix on your screen you can have "SCROLLABLE" - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: have you a sample code or an url to see how to implent this ?

Comment: I posted link to official documentation above. You Google examples. There are many like http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html